# What's wrong with kepler reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, kepler

I'm a junior developer. I tried to use kepler, but have this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kepler.gl/reducers'

File include next code:

```
import keplerGlReducer from "kepler.gl/reducers";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import {taskMiddleware} from "react-palm/tasks";
export default createStore(keplerGlReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(taskMiddleware));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: hi Ivan, are you sure you have a kepler package installed ?

Comment: hi. was need to write npm i 'kepler.gl/reducers' with npm i 'kepler', its work now. thanks for trying to help